# How to strip executables thoroughly

Tags: linux, gcc, executable, elf, strip

I'd like to strip as much as I can - on Linux: an ELF. I only want in there the stuff I need to run it.

I tried using `strip`:

```
strip --strip-all elf
```

But it doesn't seem to do a good job: `nm` still displays lots of stuff, and the binary is still big.

What should I do?

Comment: How did you build it to begin with?

Comment: I realise that this question was asked a long time back. I'm assuming that you've built it to be a dynamically linked binary. You may get more satisfactory results if you create a statically linked ELF file and then strip it.

Comment: @peoro The comment from Ignacio is relevant. Adding `-s` to gcc will empty the symbol table.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If everything else fails, you could read the documentation, starting with `man strip`.

Seriously, maybe your application has a lot of symbols and code.  At one extreme, the biggest size reduction would be `rm elf` but then your program won't run anymore.  It all depends on *your program* and what you coded into it.

As a concrete example, I recently worked with a large C++ library where `strip` without further arguments reduced the size from 400+mb to about 28 mb.  But then you could not link anymore against it (in the context of other shared libraries), rendering it somewhat useless.

But when using `strip --strip-unneeded`, it changed the size from 400+ mb to 55 mb which is still considerable, yet allowed the library to be accessed from other shared libraries.

In short, I'd trust `strip`.  Maybe your application cannot be reduced any further without code changes.

Comment: Cheeky comment concerning the `rm` command, but the `--strip-unneeded` seems to be the important note.  Without performing this, I also see the `gcc` `-s` flag as a nice answer from another comment, but may be too much for library linking as mentioned here.

Answer (score 16):

Using the -R option to strip, you can strip away all sections you don't need. Also look at [this](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) regarding minimal ELF executables.

Answer (score 8):

I would check out this great article that goes into depth on making an ELF executable as small as possible. Maybe it has info that could help!

http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Answer (score 2):

```
strip -R .comment
gcc -Os elf.c
```

Those two might help.

Answer (score 0):

to strip all symbols, use `-s` or `--strip-all`